# npm start for react native gives error Windows 10

Tags: reactjs, npm, native

I made a react native project and when I try to run it by **"npm start"**.
It gives the error:

```
> @ start E:\React\amazingApp
> expo start

Starting project at E:\React\amazingApp
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Faizan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-09T13_43_50_634Z-debug.log
```

Please help me. Thanks!

---

**Edit:**

This is my *package.json*:

```
{
  "main":"node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts":{
    "start":"expo start",
    "android":"expo start --android",
    "ios":"expo start --ios",
    "web":"expo start --web",
    "eject":"expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies":{
    "expo":"^35.0.0",
    "react":"16.8.3",
    "react-dom":"16.8.3",
    "react-native":"github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web":"^0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies":{
    "babel-preset-expo":"^7.1.0"
  },
  "private":true
}
```

Comment: have you tried by expo start? can you share your package.json

Comment: Hi Gaurav Roy, I got same error when tried expo start.